# How to fetch past 30 days data from dynamo db

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I want to fetch the past 30 days data from dynamo db. I can only able to fetch only one id at a time. How can i get all the data of 30 days from dynamo db.

```
$sevenDaysAgo = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('30 days')); 
echo  $response = $dynamodb->query([ 'TableName' => 'notifications',
'KeyConditionExpression' => 'id = :id and date_time >= :datess',     'ExpressionAttributeValues' =>  [ ':id' => ['S' => '350'],
':datess' => ['S' => $sevenDaysAgo] ],
 'ProjectionExpression' => 'id', 'ConsistentRead' => true ]);
```

Comment: What is the issue? The expectation is not clear in the post. Please update the post.

Comment: I want to get past 30 days data from dynamo db. I can only able to fetch one data . How can i get all the data from db  ( like in sql we use * to fecth the data)

Comment: What is your partition key and range key? Is "date_time" a range key? Have you defined date_time as String? Can you show some sample data? I should be able to help if you give these details. What AWS SDK are you using ? I can give the solution in Java, JS, NodeJS.

Comment: I am using php sdk.

Comment: Item{3}
 
date_timeString: 2016-10-17 06:08:02
 
idString: 351
 
messageString:  23.328 Rs. per month

Comment: these are my sample data having id, item, message as strings. I am totally new to dynamo db . Help me out with this .I imported the mysql tables to dynamo by running boto3 script.

Comment: You can't query the database if you would like to filter the data by date_time alone (i.e. without partition key). You need to scan the entire database. Refer this link for the difference between Scan and Query http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use the new TTL feature, Streams, and Lambda to maintain a sliding 30 day window of data in a new table called sliding. Steps:

1. Create a new table called `sliding` with the same schema as your base table. This table should have TTL enabled on an attribute named `myttl`.
2. Enable your original table's DynamoDB Stream with both old and new images.
3. Attach a lambda function to your original table's Stream. This lambda would write all item creations/updates/deletions from the base table to the sliding table.
4. It seems like each item might already contain a timestamp. Scan your original table and add a N attribute called `myttl` equal to timestamp+30 days in epoch time, if the item's timestamp was in the last 30 days.

The result of steps 1-4 will be a table sliding that contains an eventually consistent view of the last 30 days worth of data.